# Update a file inside dropbox

Tags: python, csv, dropbox

How can I update a csv file kept inside dropbox through my python program. At the moment I am update using my local path and i am able to read the file through the share link (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/oxgyjxambind2dy/RSS.csv) in my python code. 
Please provide some hint how to use urllib to open a csv file from dropbox and update it.

Thank you!

Comment: Why can you not use the dropbox client and let it automatically update from the local copy?

Comment: You can read a Dropbox file from its share link and process it, for example using [Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/); however, if you want to update the file in Dropbox after that, you will need to take a look at the [Dropbox developers site](https://www.dropbox.com/developers). Or, if you have Dropbox running in the system and you know the local Dropbox folder, you can just change the file locally and let the client handle the update.

Comment: Currently I have to open the csv file kept in dropbox in append mode and update it time to time and save it there so that others can see the updates.
i am doing as 'Javidcf' mentioned but then while hosting the code somewhere the path becomes invalid and hence the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/python. When you create an app, you can get an access token for your own account (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/94/generate-an-access-token-for-your-own-account), and then just use `get_file` and `put_file` to read and write the file.